# String comparision in Apache free marker

Tags: string, chatbot, freemarker, data-processing

I have a `list` which contains below values. The `list` Gets data from `restAPI`.
I know how to compare record but list has many values so i dont know how to search in array or in list. for eg list has below values. I need to check whether particular record exist in list or not.

```
var items= [
            {
                "organizationCode": "FP1",
                "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
            },
            {
                "organizationCode": "T11",
                "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
            }, 
            {
                "organizationCode": "PD2",
                "organizationName": "Product development Org"
            },
            {
                "organizationCode": "PD1",
                "organizationName": "Product1 development Org"
            },
            {
                "organizationCode": "MD1",
                "organizationName": "Main development Org"
            }
        ]

        I have to search value based on organizationName.
        I tried 

items.organizationName?contains(<input>)
```

But not working

I could not get any material so seeking help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Please give some context about the situation/use case, what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi @BertJanSchrijver  ,I have updated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830354/searching-value-in-a-list-in-apache-free-marker/61834031#61834031

Comment: It always returns false

Comment: I dont know if any search type method exist in freemarker or not, or even if i know how to iterate record like loop and then compare....I think that will help.

Comment: @ddekany Can you give me an example by making list and then searching an element, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `items.organizationName` is an error already, since `items` is purely a list, so it has no named sub-variables directly. (You may saw that pattern when `items` is coming from XML, where you can get the list of sub-elements like that. But same doesn't work with plain lists.) So, what you need is this expression:

```
items?map(it -> it.organizationName)?seq_contains(input)
```

Slightly related, but sometimes you want to retrieve the list of matching items (so you also will have the `organizationCode`), in which case you should write `items?filter(it -> it.organizationName == input)`.

Note that `?map` and `?filter` was added in FreeMarker 2.3.29.

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_filter
- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_map

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on this please?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032594/contain-in-apache-free-marker