# Contain in Apache free marker

Tags: regex, freemarker, data-processing

I have below  object returned by a particular function

```
    {"count":3,
      "items":[
       {
        "organizationCode": "FP1",
        "organizationName": "FTE Process Org"
      },
      {
        "organizationCode": "T11",
        "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org"
      },
      {
        "organizationCode": "M1",
        "organizationName": "Seattle Manufacturing"
      } ]
};
```

user has to search whether particular string exist in this object or not.
If user need to search `T11` then he can enter either `T11` or `'T11'` or `"T11"` . all this case should be accepted. If user enteres `T1` then it should not be accepted(I am mentioning because `T11` contains `T1`). if user enters `"Seattle Manufacturing"` it should be accepted
I am trying to use `contain` method but its not working. How can I do that?

I am struggling because there is very little material available regarding freemarker

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does the search need to be a complete match? case sensitive? etc...

Comment: it should be case insensitive. yes it should be complete match. "Seattle Manufacturing" should return true but if there is spelling error it should be false. fp1 or FP1 should return true but  only fp or FP should return false

Comment: Are you sure handling this should belong to FreeMarker? It doesn't sound like that. What gives that result back? Is it a Java call on the back-end? Then maybe you should process the user input and do the filtering there, and the template just shows the result.

Comment: We are using freemarker in otacle digital assistant(chatbot). Indeed it was a java call and above object was returned from restAPI. After result came, we have to compare in chatbot with user input. in chatbot  we are using apche freemarker.   is the above scenario possible in apache free marker?

Comment: @ddekany Could you please help me on the same, Please?

Comment: What variables are exposed to the template, and what type of values are they. Like, that JSON you show, let's call it `choices`, do you get it as a single string (which is bad news), or you can access parts of it in FreeMarker like `choices.items[0].organizationCode`? And again, can't the REST service be more functional and not push this on the template? Again, it's quite atypical for a template to do things like this.

Comment: Actually rest is already designed. We need to customize output based on our need. I am getting output as json only.

Answer (score 1):

So the first step would be to accept the user input. Then if they include `'` or `"` in their query, strip those characters off of their search. It's not necessary for this pattern. Once you've done that, you can use this pattern to find matches `(?<=organization(?:Name|Code)":)\s+(?i)"T11"`. You'll want to replace the `T11` portion of the pattern with whatever their stripped query is. This will not be case sensitive. If you need the pattern to be case sensitive you can remove the `(?i)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0J7ZEm/2)

Comment: its not working for 'T11' or "T11"  .double quote and single quote are part of user input.

Comment: Your answer implies that OP has to searching in a flat text JSON dump of the data. That would be an awful situation. This is structured data there. I'm hoping OP doesn't get it as a single big `String`. If he/she does, then it has to be parsed first (looks like JSON to me).

Comment: @ShrutiSharma as I mentioned in the very first part of my answer, if they use single or double quotes in their query, remove them from the query string.

Comment: @ddekany you're correct, but if it's not a JSON string then the solution isn't a regex solution anyway. They asked a regex tagged question so I made assumptions based on that.

Comment: @ddekany yes it is JSON returened by API. I have to search what user entered is exist in API output or not. is it possible in freemarker?